# setContentView in OnLongClick Listener

Tags: android, layout, onlongclicklistener

i got a problem with setContentView which throws me a null pointer.

In my mainFrame i got a small SurfaceView which takes about 50% of the screen.
I wanted to implement a method which makes that SurfaceView go Full Screen if you long clicked it. I did it like this:

```
final FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);
frame.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    boolean clicked = false;
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        if (clicked){
            clicked = false;
            (MyActivity.this).setContentView(R.layout.main);    
        } else {
            clicked = true;
            (MyActivity.this).setContentView(R.layout.fullScreen);
        }

        return true;
    }
});
```

Can someone help me how to fix this problem?

Greetings

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="right"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1" 
android:background="@drawable/background_new" >

<TextView

    android:text="@string/measures"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text_measures"
    android:textColor="#ff444444"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    />

<ImageButton
android:contentDescription="@string/desc_edge"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text_measures"
android:id="@+id/edges_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/edges_black"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
android:onClick="edge_handler"
android:background="@null"              
 />

<FrameLayout
    android:background="@xml/border"
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/text_measures"        
     >
   </RelativeLayout>
```

I know it looks like a FrameLayout but dont get fooled it was done by someone else and it is actually a SurfaceView.

Comment: see this https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/wj4uc0J9yT0

Comment: somehow that didnt help to solve my problem

Comment: setContentView() does not have visual impact until *after* onCreate()
returns. If you call it twice, the net is that the user will only see
the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the layout parameters of the SurfaceView onLong click of frame. No need to setContentView again.

```
  LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

  surfaceView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: I understand, but i get now a ClassCast Exception. I think its because my FrameLayout is already set on Fill Parent however since im using it in a RelativeLayout with those LayoutParams it wont work

Comment: post your layout file, so that i can suggest you why you are getting error.